# Проверьте, ошибка с мини калькулятором

Tags: python, калькулятор

При срабатывании кода, число всегда плюсуется. То есть не срабатывает остальные три elif. Например в `input` пишу число 5 и 3. Когда `quest` даю значение **increase** (умножить). Код не срабатывает правильно и выводит 8 (плюс).

```
x = int(input("Input your first number: "))
y = int(input("Input your second number: "))

quest = str(input("What do you want? Plus or Minus, Increase or Divide?: "))
if quest == "plus" or "Plus":
    c = x + y
    print(c)
elif quest == "minus" or "Minus":
    c = x - y
    print(c)
elif quest == "increase" or "Increase":
    c = x * y
    print(c)
elif quest == "divide" or "Divide":
    c = x / y
    print(c)
```

Comment: забыл добавить ```x = int(input("Input your first number: "))```

Comment: Добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! Добавьте метку языка программирования в ваш вопрос. [Отредактируйте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1437923/edit) ваш вопрос и добавьте все необходимые детали туда.

Comment: Опишите в вашем вопросе более детально 1) какой результат вы получаете (что выводит ваша программа?) 2) какой результат вы хотите получить (что должна выводить ваша программа?)